# Disassociate Firebase Hosting from domain and remove certificate error

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I deleted a firebase project. I had linked to a custom domain, and now I cannot access the custom domain. It gives me an error, NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
The domain is [http://apps.diggle.tech/](https://apps.diggle.tech/) and it gets redirected to https when I visit the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site is no longer associated with Firebase Hosting, however Firebase Hosting does add [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) headers to sites to ensure they're always served over HTTPS. These are cached in the browser for a period of time, and so since you had previously visited the Firebase Hosting version of your site it is still enforcing HTTPS.

Since your new hosting setup doesn't support HTTPS, you're seeing an SSL error. You will need to either add SSL to your new hosting configuration or just wait for the HSTS cache to expire.

Comment: I also have this problem. How long does it take for the HSTS cache to expire?